# How to read the same xml tag using Stax parser

Tags: java, xml, stax

```
<Product>
<SupplyDetail>
<Price>
 <PriceTypeCode>01</PriceTypeCode>
  <DiscountCoded>
    <DiscountCodeType>02</DiscountCodeType>               
    <DiscountCodeTypeName>LSI</DiscountCodeTypeName>
    <DiscountCode>25</DiscountCode></DiscountCoded>
 <PriceAmount>29.95</PriceAmount>
 <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
</Price>
</SupplyDetail>
<SupplyDetail>
<Price>
  <PriceTypeCode>08</PriceTypeCode>
  <PriceAmount>14.32</PriceAmount>
  <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
</Price>
</SupplyDetail>
</Product>
```

I want the output as

```
Pricetypecode  : 01
PriceAmount  : 29.95
Currencycode  : INR

Pricetypecode : 08
Price Amount  : 14.32
Currencycode  : INR
```

BulkFileXMLReader2.java

```
import com.main.Query.Query;
import com.main.Bean.PriceDetail;
import com.main.Bean.SpecificationBook;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, XMLStreamException, FileNotFoundException, SQLException {
String fileName = "D:\\SOFTWARE\\txt20160401.xml";
List<SpecificationBook> bookspec = (List<SpecificationBook>) parseXML(fileName);
for(SpecificationBook bean : bookspec){
System.out.println("The Price type code 08="+bean.priceTypeCode);
      System.out.println("The price amount 08 is:"+bean.priceAmount);
      System.out.println("The Currency Code 08 is:"+bean.currencyCode);
      System.out.println("The price typecodechar 01 is:"+bean.priceTypeCodeChar);
      System.out.println("The price amount 01 is:"+bean.priceAmount2);
      System.out.println("The Currency code 01 is:"+bean.currencyCode1);
}
}
private static List<SpecificationBook> parseXML(String fileName) throws ClassNotFoundException, XMLStreamException {
    List<SpecificationBook> empList = new ArrayList<>();
    SpecificationBook emp = null;

    XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, true);
    try {
        XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(fileName));

   while(xmlEventReader.hasNext()){
            XMLEvent xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
           if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()){
               StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();
if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Product")){

                   emp = new SpecificationBook();
                   }
else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("PriceTypeCode")){
                   xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();

emp.setPriceTypeCode(xmlEvent.asCharacters().toString());
               }
                else   
if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("PriceAmount")){
xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
emp.setPriceAmount(xmlEvent.asCharacters().toString());
}
else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("CurrencyCode")){
xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
emp.setCurrencyCode(xmlEvent.asCharacters().toString());
               }
           }
if(xmlEvent.isEndElement()){
               EndElement endElement = xmlEvent.asEndElement();

if(endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Product")){
empList.add(emp);
               }
           }

        }
 } catch (FileNotFoundException | XMLStreamException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return empList;
 }
```

My Pojo class.
  SpecificationBook.java

```
  public class SpecificationBook {

@Getter @Setter public String recordReference;
@Getter @Setter public String titleText;
@Getter @Setter public String imprintName;
@Getter @Setter public String publisherName;
@Getter @Setter public String illustrationDesc;
@Getter @Setter public String noofPages;
@Getter @Setter public String priceTypeCode;
@Getter @Setter public int book_id;   
@Getter @Setter public String editionversionnumber;
@Getter @Setter public String recordreference1;
@Getter @Setter public String recordreference2;
@Getter @Setter public String recordreference3  ;
@Getter @Setter public String priceTypeCodeChar;
@Getter @Setter public String priceAmount;
@Getter @Setter public String priceAmount2;
@Getter @Setter public String currencyCode;
@Getter @Setter public String currencyCode1;
}
```

I tried to get the value from the supply detail `<price>` tag values. While run this code. i got the values from the second `<SupplyDetail>` tag values only.

While run this code in my machine I got the output as

```
The Price type code 08=08
The price amount 08 is:14.83
The Currency Code 08 is:INR 
The price typecodechar 01 is:null
The price amount 01 is:null
The Currency code 01 is:null
```

Comment: are you open to non-pull based answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never invoke the setters for `priceTypeCodeChar`, `priceAmount2` and `currencyCode1` - so those will always print `null`.

Additionally, `SpecificationBook` is created for each `Product` tag and added to the result list when you encounter the `Product`'s close tag. This way the values will be overwritten for every new `Price`.

The easiest way to fix this would be to change your `SpecificationBook` class, remove the `Price` specific fields and add a list of `Price` objects.

```
class SpecificationBook {
    // other fields
    List<Price> prices;
}
```

where the `Price` class would look something like

```
class Price {
    String priceAmount;
    String priceTypeCode;
    String currencyCode;
}
```

You could then check the start-tags for `Price`, add the details and, when you encounter the `Price` end-tag, add it to the `SpecificationBook`'s `prices`.

Comment: -thanks for the answer. Like wise i have so many tags having the same tag name. For that also i want to put  separate  POJO classes? @nyname00

Comment: @Arunselvan when you need to map large parts of an XML using Stax it is usually a good idea to "mirror" (parts of) the XML structure with classes - this makes it a lot easier to write the parser.

Comment: my xml file size is more than 2gb. so only i used to do Stax parser